# Сравнить значения с сайта в приложении

Tags: android, get

Нужно реализовать нечто подобное "Проверка версии приложения".
Нужно подключится к сайту и получить от туда Timestamp для проверки актуальности новостей, в случаи если дата на сервере меняется появляется уведомление.
Как реализовать проверку? (нужно создать html файл на сервере и код HTTP Get
?)
И как проверять в главном активити ли нужно создать пред. глав. активность?

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать сервис, которые периодически опрашивает этот адрес (http get), хранит timestamp или код последней версии/новости, и если на сервере возникает еще одна версия/новость, то сервис выдает уведомление пользователю, что ему необходимо обновить версию приложения или обновить новостную ленту.
Для обновления новостной ленты, создавать новую активность не нужно.

Comment: Немного не правильно я там написал, с сервисом понятно но мне не обязательно чтобы все обновлялось в рел тайм. Мне достаточно проверки при открытии приложения, popup  хочу просто диалоговое окно выводить при запуске. Я просто хочу узнать обязательно ли писать эту массу кода для http запроса типа

Comment: AsyncTask или можно как то проще типо jsoup у меня уже подключен может им вытаскивать или okhttp пример кода бы?